# Cloudformation complains "array items are not unique"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The cloudformation template is valid, but giving an error which seems to be undocumented.

`Properties validation failed for resource MoodleRDS with message: #/VPCSecurityGroups: array items are not unique`

Code is uploaded at github because it was too long for the post.

```
https://github.com/rkhyd/MoodleQuickStart/blob/main/MoodleQuickStartv2.json
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

I checked in the documentation, but could not find any such reference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to provide values of all `Parameters` that you have used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually pretty clear. It says that you have values in your security groups list that are not unique.  Here's what you put :

```
"VPCSecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "DBSecGroup",
                        "GroupId"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ref": "DBSecGroup"
                }
            ],
```

What you did here is, you put 2 values in your list, but they are actually the same value... `Fn:GetAtt` will give you the `DBSecGroup` id, and the same will happen with `"Ref":"DBSecGroup"` which means that effectively, you put 2 values that are exactly the same in the list. Remove one of those and it will be ok.

Comment: Thank you it worked after i removed the reference part